# I have to cast the first two octets from int to byte but not the other octets. Why?

Tags: java

```
byte[] ipAddr = new byte[] {(byte) 142, (byte) 250,68,46};
```

I am getting to know the various java net functions and I have to cast the first two octets to a byte in order for it to compile.

Otherwise I get this error

```
java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

Any idea why I have to cast specifically the first octets and not all? Why does java take it as an int instead of a byte?

Comment: Because a literal integer without trailing integer suffix is deemed to be `int` by default.

Answer (score 2):

In java, bytes are 8-bit signed datatypes, so the value ranges from -128 to +127. Your first two values are greater than the maximum so you need to manually allow the conversion (by casting, in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Those two octets just happen to be larger than the maximum value allowed in a byte which is 127 (2^7-1). Any value greater than 127 will have to be cast (or dealt with more carefully) and you'll lose data in a straight cast due to the size difference. See here for more: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#:~:text=Primitive%20values%20do%20not%20share,value%20of%20127%20(inclusive)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html#:%7E:text=Primitive%20values%20do%20not%20share,value%20of%20127%20(inclusive)).

Answer (score 0):

@Dennis is on the right track, but the explanation is a bit more complicated than that.

1. Normally, an `int` valued expression cannot be assigned to a `byte` variable without a cast.
2. When the `int` valued expression is a *constant expression*, AND when the value of the expression is within the range of `byte`, then the assignment to a `byte` variable is allowed without a cast.

   However, this only applies in *assignment contexts*, and only for *constant expressions* that satisfy the JLS definition.

In your example, the integer literals are all constant expressions, but the first two are not in the required range for lossless assignment ot a `byte`; i.e -128 to +127.